# Aligning a shapefile to raster and assign values to overlay, then return as array?

Tags: python, gis, raster, shapefile

My goal is to align a shapefile to a raster basemap, and assign 1 to the cells that overlap and 0 to the ones that don't, eventually returning an array that contains lat, lon, time, and the binary variable (1/0).

Here's the plan: 1) create raster of region from array, 2) rasterize polygon shapefiles, 3) align rasterized shapefiles with base raster, 4) pixels that overlap will be assigned 1 and those that don't will be 0, 5) convert rasters to array.

I've been able to do steps 1 & 2 (see code below), but I've been stuck on step 3 for a long time. How do I align the two rasters?

You can find the files here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pecptfepac18s2y/AADbxFkKWlLqMdiHh-ICt4UYa?dl=0

Here's the code I used to create a flat grid of BC as basemap:

```
import gdal, osr
import numpy as np

#define parameters
#units = km
grid_size = 5
BC_width  = 700
BC_length = 1800

def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):
    
    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]
    originX = rasterOrigin[0]
    originY = rasterOrigin[1]
    
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()



def main(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):
    reversed_arr = array[::-1] # reverse array so the tif looks like the array
    array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,reversed_arr) # convert array to raster



if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = np.zeros([int(BC_length/grid_size),int(BC_width/grid_size)])  #140x360
    for i in range(1,100):
        array[i] = 100
    rasterOrigin = (-139.72938, 47.655534) #lower left corner of raster
    newRasterfn = '/temp/test.tif'
    cols = array.shape[1] #shape of an array (aka # of elements in each dimension)
    rows = array.shape[0]
    originX = rasterOrigin[0]
    originY = rasterOrigin[1]
    pixelWidth = 5
    pixelHeight = 5
```

Here's the code I used to rasterize polygon shapefiles

```
import ogr, gdal, osr

output_raster = '/testdata/poly.tif'

shapefile = "/testdata/20180808.shp"

def main(shapefile):

    #making the shapefile as an object.
    input_shp = ogr.Open(shapefile)
    
    #getting layer information of shapefile.
    shp_layer = input_shp.GetLayer()
    
    #pixel_size determines the size of the new raster.
    #pixel_size is proportional to size of shapefile.
    pixel_size = 0.1
    
    #get extent values to set size of output raster.
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = shp_layer.GetExtent()
    
    #calculate size/resolution of the raster.
    x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
    y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
    
    #get GeoTiff driver by 
    image_type = 'GTiff'
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(image_type)
    #passing the filename, x and y direction resolution, no. of bands, new raster.
    new_raster = driver.Create(output_raster, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    
    #transforms between pixel raster space to projection coordinate space.
    new_raster.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_size))
    
    #get required raster band.
    band = new_raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    
    #assign no data value to empty cells.
    no_data_value = -9999
    band.SetNoDataValue(no_data_value)
    band.FlushCache()
    
    #main conversion method
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(new_raster, [1], shp_layer, burn_values=[255])
    
    #adding a spatial reference
    new_rasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    new_rasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    new_raster.SetProjection(new_rasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    return output_raster
```

I'm doing everything in Python as I don't have access or funding to paid GIS software. I'm totally new to geospatial data processing... not sure if I'm taking the right approach. Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout 'rasterio.mask.mask' from the rasterio library. I think it will help.